# Gulp browsersync basedir

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm working on localhost and I'm trying to use browsersync. I want to point it to my root directory, which is http://localhost:8080/site/

What should I write here:

```
server: {
    baseDir: ""
}
```

I tried ./ but didn't work.

It keeps redirecting me to http://localhost:3000/​ and getting this message: Cannot GET /

Here is my whole code:

```
browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: ""
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try setting a `port` property to `8080` or `proxy` property to `localhost:8080` inside the object passed to the `browserSync.init` function?

Comment: I tried this, but not sure if this is the proper way to do it: ui: {
    port: 8080
}

Comment: That sets the port for browsersync's UI, which is supposed to be separate from the main port. By default, the UI is accessed at `8080` and browsersync looks at port `3000` for the projects, unless otherwise specified. You might want to keep that option and set the `port` value to `8081` to prevent conflicts.

Comment: It's the same if I set it to 8081

Comment: Did you try setting the `port` or `proxy` properties as I mentioned?

Comment: Where do I set the port?

Comment: See my initial comment: port and proxy are properties set on the object you pass to the browserSync.init function.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work:     browserSync.init({
            notify: false,
            server: {
                baseDir: "./",
                port: 8081
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

Using baseDir won't work in combination with PHP (takes only a static site)

Try proxy instead like the others suggested, and set a port.

Here's the code snippet:

```
browserSync.init({
        port: 8080,
        proxy: "http://localhost:8080/site/"
    });
```

Note that it's not under 'server' anymore, like the code in your question.